# Replace favicon on youtube with a jquery string in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, favicon, inspector

I need to replace the href with something like `href"https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfl8qSV2F.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

How can i do this with a jquery/javascript string?

*My suggestion so far:
This should work with an tag but does NOT seem to work with the `<link>` tag.*

```
$("link[href='https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfl8qSV2F.ico']").attr('href', 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico')
```

*I'm looking for a fast way to replace a favicon on a webpage without with executing a javascript string in the console.*

Comment: `$("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr('href', 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico')` seems to work ok

Answer (score 2):

The `link` element probably doesn't have the full path of the shortcut icon in the `href` attribute, it's probably a relative path. Searching on an attribute searches for **exactly** that text in the attribute.

I'd look for the `rel` attribute instead:

```
$("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr("href", "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
```

Or you can use the "ends with" form of the attribute selector (more [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings)):

```
$("link[href$='/favicon-vfl8qSV2F.ico']").attr("href", "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
```

...but I'd use `rel`.

---

You've said you're adding jQuery to the page to do this. There's no need, use the DOM instead:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
```

Comment: Did you try run them on youtube? Does not work for me, i get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function"

Comment: I works now. I forget to add jQuery:
https://blog.wplauncher.com/run-jquery-in-chrome-console/
Do you have a slim string to load jquery from console?

Comment: @TimPeterson - You could use `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("<script src='/path/to/jquery.js'><\/script>");`, but there's no reason to add jQuery just for this; I've added a non-jQuery option to the answer.